# Filter the output of find command

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I would like to move the last few files of the `find` command's output. The only way I can think of is:

```
find ~/place -iname '*.mp4' -ok mv{} ~/someplace \;
```

However, there are so many files that it becomes tedious to keep typing `no` for the ones i do not want to move. Moreover, the ones I am interested in all have capital letters in them. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There are lots of ways to filter the output, if the files you don't want to move have something in common...

Comment: So, what files do you want to move if you don't want to move _all_ of the .mp4 files?

Comment: @OwenHines There are lectures and movie snippets that I took.

Comment: Is there a specific format/pattern for the files that you want that distinguish them from the others?

Comment: @Zanna yeah the have something in common, they all have capital letters in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the filename is entirely capital letters except for the `.mp4` part, you can use `find`'s `-regex` option:

```
find ~/place -regex '.*/[A-Z]*.mp4' -exec mv -t ~/someplace {} +
```

If the `mp4` is also uppercase, then modify accordingly. Using `mv -t ~/someplace` lets you use `-exec ... {} +` form, so that multiple files are moved together. The `.*/` matches the path before the filename.

Comment: Thanks that worked out. So sad I can't upvote your answer :(

Comment: @samuel that's alright